# Passing File Directly to esriRequest Instead of Using Form Upload?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The `esriRequest` is used for retrieving data from a remote server or uploading a file. The request has a `Form` option which is used if the request is to upload a file. We specify the form element that contains the file input control here (as shown below).

```
request({
    url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
    content: myContent,
    form: dom.byId('uploadForm'),
    handleAs: 'json',
    load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
    if (response.error) {
      errorHandler(response.error);
      return;
    }
    var layerName = response.featureCollection.layers[0].layerDefinition.name;
      addShapefileToMap(response.featureCollection);
    }),
    error: lang.hitch(this, errorHandler)
});
```

Now, I need to pass a file directly to the options instead of using HTML File Dialog and Input. Something like:

```
var data = "www.domain.com/GIS/App.ZIP";
 request({
 ....,
 form: data,
 ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to browsers security , you can't make an automatic selection of a file , hence in the case of `IE` only you can create a function on load (`dojo/ready`) , that will simulate a click on a hidden input file , and this will open a window to select your Zip file .

Otherwise it's not possible in other browser like Chrome Or Firefox .

Comment: thank you both for commenting but what I need is not loading from client machine!  I need to pass the zip file which is sitting on the server. like referencing to a URL in ajax call
var data = "www.domain.com/GIS/App.ZIP";

Comment: is this file located in the same app server ?

Comment: yes it is in the same server